# Make objects slide across the screen in random positions

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprites, random

I want to make an object appear randomly at the right hand side of the screen and then slide across the screen and disapear at the left hand side. I am working with libgdx. I have this bit of code but it makes items fall from the top down. Please help.

```
public EntityManager(int amount, OrthoCamera camera) {
    player = new Player(new Vector2(15, 230), new Vector2(0, 0), this, camera);
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        float x = MathUtils.random(0, MainGame.HEIGHT - TextureManager.ENEMY.getHeight());
        float y = MathUtils.random(MainGame.WIDTH, MainGame.WIDTH * 10);
        float speed = MathUtils.random(2, 10);
        addEntity(new Enemy(new Vector2(x, y), new Vector2(-0, -speed)));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your last line:

`addEntity(..., new Vector2(-0, -speed)));`

Speed is set on the Y-axis, which is vertically; you want to replace it with:

`addEntity(..., new Vector2(-speed, 0)));`

Incidentally, your code flips the "normally" understood X and Y coordinates; you're using `x` to indicate vertical position, and `y` to indicate horizontal position.

Also, my two cents: setting a random speed from 1x to 10x with screen width is too much. I would use a smaller range, like 1x-5x (for the line `float y = ...`).

Answer (score 0):

X is horizontal, Y is vertical. You always give these "coordinates" in this order (First X, then Y). This should fix it:

```
addEntity(new Enemy(new Vector2(x, y), new Vector2(-speed, 0)));
```

With this in mind you need to change spawning position as well (I made some comments):

```
public EntityManager(int amount, OrthoCamera camera) {
    player = new Player(new Vector2(15, 230), new Vector2(0, 0), this, camera);
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        float x = MathUtils.random(0, MainGame.HEIGHT - TextureManager.ENEMY.getHeight()); //This should be float y, vertical height
        float y = MathUtils.random(MainGame.WIDTH, MainGame.WIDTH * 10); //This should be float x, horizontal width.
        float speed = MathUtils.random(2, 10);            

addEntity(new Enemy(new Vector2(x, y), new Vector2(-0, -speed)));
}
```